# Struggling to add and remove blank lines with ruamel roundtrip

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a large YAML file where I need to add 2 key-values to the end of one item.
Here is an example of the format of the original file:

```
repo1:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team

repo2:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
```

I want the output to look like:

```
repo1:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
  archived: true
  archived_date: sample date

repo2:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
```

I'm using ruamel.yaml as roundtrip keeps the formatting and comments at the top of this large file. My code to do this is as follows, it takes an input of repo_name which is the item I want to add onto:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open("repos.yml", "r") as file:
  repos = yaml.load(file)
for repo in repos.items():
  if repo_name == repo[0]:
    repo[1].update({"archived": bool("true"), "archived_date": datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')})
    break
  else:
    continue

with open("repos.yml", "w") as processed_file:
  yaml.default_flow_style = False
  yaml.width = float("inf")
  yaml.dump(repos, processed_file)
```

This nearly does what I want but the output looks like this:

```
repo1:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team

  archived: true
  archived_date: sample date
repo2:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
```

How can I remove the blank line before what I've included and add one after it? Printing repo[1] in the loop shows the dictionary doesn't have a blank line but I want to use roundtrip to keep the rest of the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, after loading, you would inspect the comment attribute, `.ca`, for `repos['repo1']` you would see:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'team': [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n', line: 3, col: 8), None]})
```

So the "comment" that consist of the empty EOL comment followed by an empty line (`'\n\n'`) is
attached to the `team` key, and that is the one you want to move to the new latest key:

```
import sys
from datetime import date
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_str = """
repo1:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team

repo2:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
"""

repo_name = 'repo1'

yaml = YAML()
# yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.width = 2048

repos = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for repo in repos.items():
  if repo_name == repo[0]:
    repo[1].update(dict(archived=True, archived_date=date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')))
    break
  else:
    continue

ca_items = repos['repo1'].ca.items
ca_items['archived_date'] = ca_items.pop('team')
yaml.dump(repos, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
repo1:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
  archived: true
  archived_date: 17-12-2021

repo2:
  description: sample description
  team: sample team
```

- Make sure to make your code install/check the revision number of `ruamel.yaml` with which you found
  this to work. Internals might change at some point.
- You can make the code more robust, by walking over the keys and detecting the key name of the last element and make sure it has a comment before reassigning it.
- The line and column information doesn't need updating.
- The recommended extension for YAML files (as per the yaml.org FAQ) has been `.yaml` for over 15 years.
- `bool("true")` and `bool("false")` both dump to `true` in YAML, whereas `bool("")` dumps to `false`. It
  is more clear to use `True` and `False` in your dictionary update.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked straight away and I've made some of the other changes you've suggested too